# convert time format to have amount of decimal in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe  and one column of the dataframe named "datetime" contains information of time, for example "2014-01-09 09:15:01". What I want to do is converting "2014-01-09 09:15:01" to "2014-01-09 09:15:01.000000". 
What I did is

```
data = pd.to_datetime(trade_data['datetime'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.f").
```

However, it does not work.

```
ValueError: time data '2014-01-20 07:05:36.500000' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How to fix this problem? Thx.

Edit
What contains in column of 'datetime'.

```
>>> data['datetime'][:20]
date
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 07:05:36.500000
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:14:00.500000
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:00.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:01
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:01.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:02
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:02.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:03
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:03.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:04
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:04.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:05
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:05.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:06
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:06.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:07
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:07.500000
2014-01-20           2014-01-20 09:15:08
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:08.500000
2014-01-20    2014-01-20 09:15:09.500000
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
s = pd.Series(["2014-01-09 09:15:01"])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
res = s.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

In [115]: res
Out[115]:
0    2014-01-09 09:15:01.000000
dtype: object
```

*Note*: It'll work with `pandas` version >= `0.17.0`

**EDIT**

For the `pandas` versions < `0.17.0` you could use `datetime.strftime` and `apply`:

```
from datetime import datetime
res1 = s.apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))

In [250]: res1
Out[250]:
0    2014-01-09 09:15:01.000000
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thx but it does not work. AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime'. I also can not run you example code and it gives the same error information.

Comment: It'll work with pandas version > `0.17.0`. Take a look to the link in the edited question.

Comment: @epx you could use updated version for older `pandas` versions

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But what do you mean by using updated version for older pandas version? This makes me confused.

Comment: @epx If you have `pandas` version < `0.17.0` where there is no `dt` functionality you could `apply` `lambda` function with `datetime.strftime` as in the **edited** part of the answer. It'll work for every pandas version which has `apply` functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
print df
                              datetime
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:00.500000
2014-01-20         2014-01-20 09:15:01
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:01.500000
2014-01-20         2014-01-20 09:15:02

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
print df
                          datetime
2014-01-20 2014-01-20 09:15:00.500
2014-01-20 2014-01-20 09:15:01.000
2014-01-20 2014-01-20 09:15:01.500
2014-01-20 2014-01-20 09:15:02.000

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print df
                              datetime
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:00.500000
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:01.000000
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:01.500000
2014-01-20  2014-01-20 09:15:02.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.